# Emailed link sends users to different locations

Tags: outlook, hyperlink, html-email

Our marketing person sent out an email containing a new signature template for company staff to update their signatures.  For most users, this leads to the intended location - `https://<ourdomain>/employment`.  However for a few staff members, this link leads to `https://<ourdomain>/about-us/employment`, which is a page that doesn't exist.

The link was delivered via Outlook and followed from Outlook Desktop.  The link code as taken from the email source is as follows:

```
    <p class=MsoNormal>
    <span style='font-size:10.0pt;font-family:"Arial",sans-serif;color:#013B49'>We are hiring! Apply at</span>
    <span style='font-size:10.0pt;font-family:"Arial",sans-serif'> 
      <a href="https://<ourdomain>/employment">
        <span style='color:#0563C1'>https://<ourdomain>/employment</span>
      </a>
      <span style='color:#013B49'>.<o:p></o:p></span>
    </span>
    </p>
```

After some testing, we've discovered that the link leads to the wrong location for those users who never changed the default browser from Edge.  For those users using Chrome, it works fine.  (Other browsers have not been tested at this time.)

My question is what could cause this and how can we fix it?  I've examined the link destination for both affected and unaffected users and they are the same.  I've also tried switching my own default browser to Edge from Chrome and opening the link, but the link worked as intended.  I've studied some web development before, and I know that accessing resources using different browser can cause strange behavior, but I'm not aware of anything that would cause this behavior.  Any advice would be appreciated.

Also, it should be noted that we use Barracuda email link protection, however since right-clicking and copying the link destination to a notepad document for both affected and unaffected users yields the same link destination, I don't believe this has an impact for this particular problem.

Comment: Outlook add-ins can alter the message body or web browsers may have extensions that replace the URL which is going to be navigated to. Look for other software that can change the content on the problematic machine.

Comment: Try also https://wheregoes.com/ to see if there are intermediate steps, although if this is on an intranet I'm not sure that method would work - but some sort of trace route?